# upload multiple files with a single file_uploader rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

In `sr_documents/form`:

```
<%= simple_form_for @service_request,:url=>upload_document_path(@service_request.id),:remote=>true,:html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

<%= f.nested_fields_for :sr_documents do |q| %>

<%= q.input :file,:required => true,:hint=>"(only .pdf,.docx,.doc,.txt)", multiple: true,:name=>'file[]' %>

<%= f.button :submit ,:class=> "btn btn-go button",data: {"disable-with" => "Processing..."}%>

<%= f.add_nested_fields_link :sr_documents,"Add new file" %>
<%end%>
```

I am using the gem `nested_form_fields` and `paperclip` in my app. Through the above code, I am able to upload multiple files. But my concern is how do I upload multiple files with a single file_uploader. I used name `file[]` and `:multiple=>true`, still its not working. Please help me out.

Comment: Multiple files using single file field? Are you kidding? It's not possible, and if someone say it is. Then even I'd like to know their answer.

Comment: well you could incorporate something like http://www.dropzonejs.com/  ?

Comment: The basic version of what you are trying to do isn't possible.  However, you can make it *seem* like that is what is happening, to the user, by having the submit button run some javascript that actually does a series of seperate file uploads using ajax. see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also needed same thing but didn't fine any solution.
In my project I am using

```
= file_field_tag :image_files, :multiple => true, name: 'image_files[]', style: 'display:none', :id => 'fileinput'
```

User just have to select multiple files after selecting this field. And in controller I am able to get all those files with params[:image_files]

I am then building images as :

```
 # This method builds images as per image_files params
  def build_images
    (params[:image_files] || []).each do |img|
      @product.images.build(file: img)
    end
  end
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: I have suggested a work around. Not claiming it as an proper answer :).